# Server Error (500) on django app production

Tags: django, django-urls, server-error, render.com

Updated, Please check the updated part.

I am trying to deploy a Django Application on Render.

In my project, I have some number of apps that have their own `urls.py` file. Then, in the project's url, I included them. Have a look at the project's url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('home.urls')),
    path('about/', include('about.urls')),
    path('kbdash/', include('management.urls')),
]
```

And for every app  the url looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('', about_page, name='about'),
]
```

all these urls work except for the `path('kbdash/', include('management.urls'))`

Below is the url of management app:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.Dashboard.as_view(), name='dashboard'),
  path('fuels/', views.fuel_list_view, name='fuel_list'),
  
]
```

all the urls in main urls file are working except for the `kbdash/`

Visiting `kbdash/` and any link under `kbdash/` throw `Server Error (500)`

View associated with `/kbdash/` url. :

```
class Dashboard(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.View):

  def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):        
    fuels = Fuel.objects.filter(status=1)

    try:
      total_sale = Sale.objects.filter(fuel__id__in = fuels).aggregate(Sum('total_amount'))['total_amount__sum']
      if total_sale is None:
        total_sale = 0
    except:
      total_sale = 0

    context = {
      'total_fuel_count': fuels.count(),
      'fuels': fuels,
      'total_sale': total_sale,
    }

    return render(request, 'management/dashboard.html', context)
```

I tried changing DEBUG to True in production to see error in browser. Doing so the url is working. But it should work even when the DEBUG is False.

I have no idea why such behaviour. On local computer it's working perfectly.

Can somebody guide me into the light...!

**Updated part:**
I used the `ADMINS` setting in `settings.py` . Now I got the error in my gmail inbox.
The error:

```
Internal Server Error: /kbdash/
ValueError at /kbdash/ Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'select2/dist/css/select2.min.css' Request Method: GET Request URL: https://kb-cng-web.onrender.com/kbdash/
```

I used select2 for select element. It's perfectly working locally. but in the production it's not available in staticfiles.

I also tried the source code but checking the url `/static/path/to/select2` shows that It's not available in production.
What might be a way to trace it?

**Base.html**

https://jsfiddle.net/8ozt2761/

**Dashboard.html**

https://jsfiddle.net/8ozt2761/1/

Comment: A 500 error can mean a lot of things, but a problem with urls usually is a page not found, 404 error.  When visiting `kbdash/`, what is the view that is activated?  In visiting these pages are there any database operations which might be failing on the production database, which I'm guessing is different?

Comment: @raphael your points are valid. I have updated the question with the view associated with /kbdash/. could you please take a look now? And yes all the views under /kbdash/  has db operation.

Comment: What does the server log say…?

Comment: @deceze This is the server error when visiting /kbdash/ : 127.0.0.1 - - [01/Dec/2023:04:22:55 +0000] "GET /kbdash/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "https://kb-cng-web.onrender.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

Comment: @raphael I want to mention I tried using the same production database from the local project using the db_url. it's working. The issue is only in the production.

Comment: That's it? Where does that log come from exactly? Is that Django's internal log, or some proxy's log?

Comment: @deceze I hosted the app on Render free server, for demonstration. And in the log tab, it generates logs for each request.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Render in particular. Your first priority needs to be to get a useful error log message. Consider switching on debug mode so it'll appear in the browser, or investigate more how to get useful error logs on Render.

Comment: @deceze Alright. I am trying with debug on. and will come back with an update, thank you for your response and time. Please keep an eye on the notification.

Comment: @deceze after switching debug on, what I found is -- any url under /kbdash/ is now working. While I'm looking into it, what's your suggestion would be in this scenario?

Comment: That depends on what "no[t] working means" and what the exact error is.

Comment: @deceze When I turned Debug=True. The url /kbdash/ and anything under it are working. meaning I am seeing the expected page. and when Debug=False, it throws Server error 500.

Comment: Err, okay?! Bizarre…

Comment: @deceze My primary problem was that, the /kbdash/ url was throwing server error. Now after changing the the Debug to True, the url is working. Why do such behavior can happen? What can be a possibility?

Comment: Update your question with these details so people other than me can try to answer this.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question, hoping someone would guide me into the light. @deceze

Comment: Doublecheck all the paths to images(and static files in general) in your kbdash templates.  Are there any malformed links?

Comment: Add your **settings.py** please.

Comment: @SamSparx I double checked all the static links. Everything is available even when checked with static url, Expect select2 's source. Please head over to the question's Updated part at the bottom. I have updated thequestion.

Comment: @raphael I managed to get the error in my inbox using the ADMINS settings. Could you please check the question again? I have updated the question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas except (1) have you run `python manage.py collectstatic`, and (2) are you running `select2` using a CDN or manually?

Comment: If `collectstatic` doesn't do the trick, can you 1) check in your local version that the .css file is where you expect it to be (hopefully somewhere where other static files are being collected from) and 2) share the part of your template where it is included (could be a rogue typo) and 3) ensure that template has {% load static %}

Comment: @raphael 1) I have run collectstatic from a .sh file in prod. 2) I have the source code in a file. then referenced in base.html using link. 3) yes locally .css file is available where it should be. (checked with static url as well- it is available locally) 4. Added the template base.html and dashboard.html for your reference. 
I want to mention one more thing. My application has 2 part, a)webstie b)management. for website I use one base.html for the management I use another base which is management_base.html. both base has their different static files

Comment: @raphael I solved it. Please have a look at my answer. And if you could give me hints why such phenomena, it would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved it.

I stored the select2 source code in the a select2 folder like this:

> select2/dist/css/select2.min.css
>
> select2/dist/js/select2.min.js

So when running the collectstatic in production it didn't find the sources in the path.

Then after so many debugging I changed the path and directly placed the min.css and min.js under select2 folder.

Now after running collectstatic it finds the path of select2.